# Create slider, hide it and show after data load

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying  to create select input and show it in sidebar only after loading data. I tried with:

`selectInput("valueinput", "VALUE",
                    choices = c("a" = "ds","b"= "dsa")),`

```
observeEvent(input$FileInput, {
    shinyjs::toggle("valueinput")
  })
```

My result is a select which disappears after loading data.

Comment: Supply a full [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `req()` might work for you if you do something like this:

server:

```
output$slider.ui <- renderUI({
req(YOUR DATAFRAME())
selectInput("valueinput", "VALUE",
                    choices = c("a" = "ds","b"= "dsa"))
})
```

ui:

```
uiOutput('slider.ui')
```